# Repainting when using security()

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

i have some problem in my pine code when i use security()

i use diffrent timeframe for chart and security() function, and its make fake alert in my strategy

i read this FAQ ([link](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)) but i can't fix my problem
can anyone help ?

```
res5 = input("45", type=input.resolution)

o = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
c = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
hz = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, res5, low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should request data from a higher time frame when the bar is closed. It is clearly stated in that FAQ.

Use this for your security calls:

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: this code make the strategy winrate Negative. is there any other way ?

Comment: Well, that is the way to do it. If it is negative, focus on the problem. This is not the problem.

Comment: The code I shared you will never repaint. If your alerts are still repainting it might be coming from somewhere else in your code.